# bitnami openldap is crashing at start time

Tags: ldap, openldap, bitnami

I'm trying to learn a bit about openLDAP but I'm facing an error. Let me show you:

I'm using bitnami/openldap:2.4.49 image and I have this environment config:

```
      LDAP_ROOT: dc=testing
      LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: true
      LDAP_ADD_SCHEMAS: "yes"
      LDAP_EXTRA_SCHEMAS: cosine, inetorgperson, nis
      LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_ENABLED: "yes"
      LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

When trying to create the container, at the first time I try, this error appears:

```
openldap  |  13:32:40.04 INFO  ==> Creating LDAP default tree
openldap  | ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
openldap  |     additional info: value of single-valued naming attribute 'dc' conflicts with value present in entry
openldap  | adding new entry "dc=testing"
openldap  |
openldap exited with code 64
```

If I try to create it again immediately afterwards, it starts to work. But it's a pain to have to do it twice, why can this happen?

Thanks.

I expect LDAP server to start smoothly at the first try to create it.